# How to make different menu item dropdowns

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

why a dropdown menu using the same menu will appear the same, how to make a dropdown menu using the same JS but look different like using bootstrap the dropdown will display the dropdown that we clicked on that will appear.

The code here doesn't display a different dropdown based on what I clicked on.

here like me

click drop 1 to display 1

and I

click drop 2 appears 1

how to make different click dropdowns, do I have to make the same 2 js with different names?

maybe someone here can help my problem

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting.

use onlick function with parameter `onclick="myFunction(num)"`.

```
function myFunction(num)
{
 document.getElementById("myDropdown"+num).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```js
function myFunction(num)
{
 document.getElementById("myDropdown"+num).classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(1)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home1</a>
    <a href="#about">About1</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(2)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home2</a>
    <a href="#about">About2</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
  </div> 
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(3)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</button>
  <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home3</a>
    <a href="#about">About3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact3</a>
  </div> 
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(4)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 4</button>
  <div id="myDropdown4" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home4</a>
    <a href="#about">About4</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact4</a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have used it that way, but if I use it to repeat database output, will the dropdown that I click be appropriate?


My problem is there, I want to compile the settings click on my post a dropdown will appear and the dropdown appears according to that post and it turns out it's not as I expected

Comment: this is good thank you, then how do you make it onclick = "myFunction (?)" based on the post id?


example from my random post 3, 7, 10, 15, 30 why am I trying not work?

onclick = "myFunction (3)"
onclick = "myFunction (7)"
onclick = "myFunction (10)"
onclick = "myFunction (15)"


Do they have to be sequential numbers?

Comment: it is not necessary to have sequential if use this  onclick="myFunction(1)" ,  it find its corresponding id (id="myDropdown1") then the corresponding div dropdown will be shown.But the id should be unique.